# python: What am I doing wrong here in my testing code?

Tags: python, testing, enums, auto

I want to understand what I'm doing here wrong.

```
from enum import Enum, auto
class colors(Enum):
    red= auto()
    green= auto()
    yellow= auto()
```

This is my class.

```
     def is_first(self):
        return self is not colors.red
```

My first function.

```
    def second(self):
        if self is colors.red:
            return ''
        elif self is green:
            return 'second_type'
        elif self is yellow:
            return 'third_type'
```

What am I doing wrong in testing I need to them all pass.

```
     @pytest.mark.parametrize('input_str, expected_result',
                    [('aa', False)])

    def test_is_first(input_str, expected_result):
        assert is_first(input_str) is expected_result
```

and for my second function

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('input_str, expected_result',
                    [('', True),
            ('second_type', True),
            ('third_type', True),
            ('aa', False)])

    def test_second(input_str, expected_result):
        assert second(input_str) is expected_result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input_str, expected_result',
                [('', True),
        ('second_type', True),
        ('third_type', True),
        ('aa', False)])

def test_second(input_str, expected_result):
    assert second(input_str) is expected_result
```

You wrote:

```
def second(self):
    if self is colors.red:
        return ''
    elif self is green:
        return 'second_type'
    elif self is yellow:
        return 'third_type'
```

This would pass the test:

```
def second(self):
    if self == '':
        return True
    elif self == 'second_type':
        return True
    elif self == 'third_type':
        return True
    elif self 'aa':
        return False
```

---

Your `assert is_first(input_str) is expected_result` is going to fail.

```
def is_first(self):
  return self is not colors.red
```

This is going to return `True` or `False`. Your `expected_result` is checking a Boolean value against a String.

Comment: I adjusted the answer. You should look up a basic pytest templates. You are still leaving out a lot of code. So just copy pasting won't solve your issue. You should understand how the test actually works before applying the tests.